# Android ExoPlayer. LoadControl. How to determine which track is loading in onTrackSelected()?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Is there any ways to determine loading track uri or its queue position? (not of currently playing track)

```
override fun onTracksSelected(renderers: Array<out Renderer>, trackGroups: TrackGroupArray, trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray) {
 // which is selected?
}
```

If i understood correctly, onTrackSelected calls when the loading track changed, not playing track.

[image]

Is there any ways to determine which track is selected? (at least its uri or queue position)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Player.EventListener.
2. Add in your exoplayer as mExoplayer.addListener(eventListener);
3. It has a method onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason)

   ```
   @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {
        Logger.w(TAG, "PLAYER POSITION DISCONTINUITY: " + reason);
        switch (positionChangedReason) {
            case ExoPlayer.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION:
                Logger.d(TAG, "Transition from one period to another");
                Logger.d(TAG, "Window Index: " + mExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex());
                Logger.d(TAG, "Position: " + mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                // Do something with current index
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply! 
Unfortunately this method does't call when the current track is completely loaded and it starts loading next track (current track is still playing).
When the next track's loading started, but current track is still playing - i receive the loadControl.onLoadedTracksChanged().
And when the player switches to next track - i see onPositionDiscontinuity().
WindowIndex shows the playing track index, but i need the index of loading track (it may be different)